# nativescript: How to use fonts that have same name in Font Book?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I followed the Nativescript guide to using custom fonts and it's been working well.  As it notes, I use the Mac default Font Book and use that exact name in the css, regardless of what the actual filename is.  However, I am using some fonts now that are coming up with the same name in Font Book.  I have files `Avenir-Next-LT-Medium.ttf`, `Avenir-Next-LT-Demi.ttf` and `Avenir-Next-LT-Regular.ttf`, all of which just show up as `Avenir Next Pro` in Font Book so I don't know how to use each individually.

Comment: Why you would want to install a font that is already on device? In case if it's a different font but name is same, you could change the name of the font with a font editor.

Comment: Those designations mean different font weights, not different font families.

Comment: @Manoj . didn't know Avenir was a system font..thank you

Comment: You may use sites like http://iosfonts.com/ to know which font exists in system.